# Redhat 7.6 network config issues

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, redhat-enterprise-linux

Having a unusual issue with a redhat 7.6 install. the network configuration is not acting as expected and i am out of ideas.

the system has 2 interfaces.  the second interface has 2 ip addresses.  here is the configuration that is being setup.

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
GATEWAY=10.135.149.1

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:50:56:aa:aa:18
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=10.135.209.29
NETMASK0=255.255.255.224

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:50:56:aa:e2:37
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR0=10.135.149.8
NETMASK0=255.255.255.224
IPADDR1=10.135.149.18
NETMASK1=255.255.255.224

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.135.209.1
```

everything looks correct except for the routing table.

```
 ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:f1:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.135.209.30/27 brd 10.135.209.31 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feaa:f172/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:e1:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.135.149.8/30 brd 10.135.149.11 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.135.149.18/30 brd 10.135.149.19 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feaa:e12a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

default via 10.135.149.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
default via 10.135.149.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 101 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.135.209.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
10.135.149.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100 
10.135.149.1 dev eth1 proto static scope link metric 101 
10.135.149.8/30 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.135.149.8 metric 101 
10.135.149.16/30 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.135.149.18 metric 101 
10.135.209.0/27 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.135.209.30 metric 100 

netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.135.149.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.135.149.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.135.209.1    255.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.135.149.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
10.135.149.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1
10.135.149.8    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 eth1
10.135.149.16   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 eth1
10.135.209.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I have no idea why but i seem to be getting 2 default routes one out eth0 and the other out eth1.  I can fix this by declaring the default gateway device but that will mean that this server will be configured different than the rest of the clusters. I have the same config applied to 91 other hosts of the same version of redhat with no issues.  what needs to change to return the expected behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  NetworkManager was still running.  the defaults where adding in the extra route.